# What is the probability that no 2 books from the same major will be placed next to each other?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

4 mathematics, 3 physics, 2 chemistry (all distinct) books are supposed to arrange on a bookshelf randomly.

What is the probability that no 2 books from the same major will be placed next to each other?

I may need to use the inclusion-exclusion formula, but I can not see a "good" solution.

Here is what I think:

I first put 4 math books.

$\bigcirc_1 M_1 \bigcirc_2 M_2 \bigcirc_3 M_3 \bigcirc_4 M_4 \bigcirc_5$

The circles 2,3,4 must be filled with physics and chemistry books. There are possibilities:

1) 2,1,1,1,0

2) 0,1,1,1,2

3) 1,1,1,1,1

4) 0,2,1,1,1

5) 1,2,1,1,0

6) 0,1,2,1,1

7) 1,1,2,1,0

8) 0,1,1,2,1

9) 1,1,1,2,0

10) 0,2,2,1,0

11) 0,2,1,2,0

12) 0,1,2,2,0

13) 0,3,1,1,0

14) 0,1,3,1,0

15) 0,1,1,3,0

Then

$\frac{8(3.2.2.3!.4!)+4!.5!+ 3(3.2.2.2.2.4!)+3.3.12.4!}{9!}=\frac{79}{1260}\approx 0.0627$

For cases 1-9, except 3: 2 books should be 1 physics and 1 chemistry. We can choose 1 out of 3 physics books, 1 out of 2 chemistry, they can be ordered 2 different ways PC or CP. The remaining 3 books can be arranged in 3! ways, 4 math books can be arranged in 4! ways. So 3.2.2.3!.4!

case 3: math books can be ordered 4! ways, other 5 books can be ordered 5! ways.

cases 10-12: we need 2 physics and 2 chemistry books for 2-2 cases. 
For instance, for 11 (2-1-2). For the leftmost 2, we need one P and one C, they could be PC or CP. So 3.2.2. For the rightmost 2, we choose one P from remaining 2 P, and there is only one C left, they could be PC or CP. So 2.2. And for math books 4!.

similar arguments for 3-1-1 cases.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That the $M$-books etc. are distinct has no significance. It remains to count the admissible arrangements of $MMMMPPPCC$ among the totally ${9!\over4!3!2!}=1260$ possible arrangements. We begin with $PPP$ and insert two $C$s in the following ways:

$$CCPPP \ (2\times), \quad PCCPP \ (2\times),\quad CPCPP \ (4\times),\quad PCPCP,\quad CPPPC\ .\tag{1}$$
The first of these has three enforced $M$s, resulting in $CMCPMPMP$, and then the last $M$ can be placed in one of the circled places here: $\ \circ CMC\circ PMPMP\circ\ $. It follows that the first entry in $(1)$ gives rise to $2\cdot3$ admissible arrangements. Doing this for all $5$ entries in $(1)$ we arrive at
$$2\cdot 3+2\cdot{4\choose2}+4\cdot{5\choose 3}+{6\choose4}+{4\choose2}=79$$
admissible arrangements.

The desired probability therefore is ${79\over1260}=0.0627$.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. Do you see where I make a mistake if there is?

Comment: @Probabilitystudent: I think your $15$ cases are o.k.; but I don't understand what you did on your last line.

Comment: I added some explanations.

Comment: I did not go through your details. To make sure I let Mathematica list the 1260 permutations and then extracted $79$ admissible ones from these. It seems that you missed just $6$ cases somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I saw my mistake and corrected.